# Initial handshakes of attacks via client-initiated renegotiation

Tags: tls, denial-of-service, starttls

As far as I understand after reading [this beautifully explained answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/71425/53572), MiTM data injection attacks via client-initiated renegotiation can only happens if the attacker is already in a connection with the server which did not check his credential. He then issues a command, and escalates his privilege by triggering a renegotiation and splicing in an authentic client's handshake, and the server will then mistake the command for one coming from an authentic client.

Similarly, according to [this post](http://www.educatedguesswork.org/2011/10/ssltls_and_computational_dos.html), the DoS attack works by an attacker first establishing a connection to a server (during which his credential is not checked), and then repeatedly trigger renegotiation on the same connection.

My question is: if I'm operating in an environment where the client's certificate is checked upon first connection, I should not be affected by this, is it correct?

A related question: if the connection is started after StartTLS, since StartTLS checks for client's certificate, are client-initiated renegotiation attacks also not applicable?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think client certificates will solve the problem of computational DoS. Consider the sequence of messages in SSL / TLS:

[image: [Source](http://www.garykessler.net/library/images/crypto_ssl.gif)]

The client certificate is sent to the server *after* the ServerKeyExchange message. In the case of [EC]DHE_RSA the ServerKeyExchange message involves the server signing the DH parameters with it's long term public key. So the server has already performed a computationally intensive operation (RSA signature) before the client even sent it it's certificate.

A better approach would be to require a [client puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_Puzzle_Protocol) to be solved in between the ClientHello and ServerHello messages.

Comment: I agree that client certificate will not solve the problem of computational DoS, in general; but I'm wondering if you can stop exploits using client-initiated renegotiation in particular, by checking client credential (if available, and I know that's rarely the case).